# An imbedding question

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Is it possible to say that
$$
H^{2}(\Omega)\cap H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)\hookrightarrow  H_{0}^{1}(\Omega).
$$

Precisely, I am dealing with this question: Is it possible to have the following estimate if we take $u\in H^{2}(\Omega)\cap H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$?
$$
\int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla u_{t} dx < \frac {d} {2}\|\Delta u\|_{2}^{2}+\frac {1}{2}\|\nabla u_{t}\|_{2}^{2}
$$
where $d$ denotes the above embedding constant and the norms $\Bigr(\int_{\Omega}|\Delta u|^{2}dx\Bigr)^{\frac {1}{2}}$ and $\Bigr(\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^{2}dx\Bigr)^{\frac {1}{2}}$ have been used in $H^{2}(\Omega)\cap H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$ and  $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$ respectively.

Comment: What norms are you using? Also, what is the meaning of your second paragraph?

Comment: The standard norm on $X \cap Y$ is $\max\{\|\cdot\|_X, \|\cdot\|_Y\}$ which makes the embedding continuous almost immediately from definition.

Comment: Is $\Omega$ a bounded domain with some regularity in the boundary?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that $\Omega$ is a bounded domain. Note that if $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega)$ then

\begin{eqnarray}
 \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 &=& \int_\Omega u\Delta u      \nonumber \\
   &\leq& \|u\|_2\|\Delta u\|_2 \nonumber \\
\end{eqnarray}

It follows from Poincare's inequality that $$\|\nabla u\|_2\leq C\|\Delta u\|_2$$

for some positive constant $C$. Now I'm assuming that $\nabla u_t\in L^2(\Omega)$, which implies

\begin{eqnarray}
 \int_\Omega \nabla u\nabla u_t &\leq& \|\nabla u\|_2\|\nabla u_t\|_2      \nonumber \\
   &\leq& C\|\Delta u\|_2\|\nabla u_t\| \nonumber \\
   &\le& \frac{C^2\|\Delta u\|_2^2}{2}+\frac{\|\nabla u_t\|^2_2}{2}
 \end{eqnarray}

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the last step goes by the name "Young's inequality".